# Insert custom div between posts

Tags: posts, query-posts

I'm using twenty twelve and I need to insert a div between the posts. I'm not sure how to stop the loop, insert the div, and then restart the loop.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: what you mean stop the loop, insert the div, and then restart the loop?

Comment: I was thinking a PHP script was used to loop through all the posts and echo them all out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your position within the loop using the `current_post` var of the `$wp_query` object, and insert markup at a specific spot or at some interval. A simple example:

```
while( have_posts() ):
    the_post();

    the_title();
    the_excerpt();

    // if current_post is 1, insert the div
    // note that current_post starts at 0,
    // so this will be after the second post's content

    if( 1 == $wp_query->current_post ):
        echo '<div>My div!</div>';
    endif;

endwhile;
```

Comment: Perfect - that's exactly what I was looking for. Does this solution have anything to do with why my posts are cut off with [...] instead of showing full text? I was thinking that they showed full text before.

Comment: change `the_excerpt()` to `the_content()` to show full post content.

Comment: Got it. Can you tell me which file that WP defines these objects/methods so I can research this on my own? I've been combining through these files for a few hours now and cannot find the methods anywhere.

Comment: You can see the internals of the query engine [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in `wp-includes/query.php`

Comment: @Milo I have a wordpress site that uses the infinite scroll for the post lists on the homepage. I want to display a div between posts too but the loop works only for the first page (8posts per page). Can you please help me out

Answer (score -1):

You can add the `<div>` right after the post is output by modifying index.php of the theme. Take a look at lines 22-25 (http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twenty-twelve/0.9/index.php), you'd place it right after line 24, which is responsible for pulling the right content type template in and displaying it.

```
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <!-- You could insert your div here -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If you wanted to get picky about which types of posts (regular posts, image posts, etc.) it comes after, then you could edit the content-*.php files themselves, and place it at the end of those templates.