# Edit value of the_content() before showing

Tags: theme-development, the-content

I have a task that needs to insert ad-tags in the middle of `the_content()` value.

But I got confused because I can't break down the value of `the_content()`.

Is there any way to put some code in the middle of `the_content()` value?

Or maybe there's an alternative to using function `while(have_post)` and print the post on the list kind of style?

Or can I just use kind of loop (like foreach) and print the data one by one while inserting the ad-tags between it?

I'm sorry I still don't know how to dump the value of `the_content()` itself, but I can only see the value by looking the inspect element. Here's the value that I know was from `the_content()`;

```
<!-- NOTE: If you need to make changes to this file, copy it to your current theme's main
    directory so your changes won't be overwritten when the plugin is upgraded. -->

<!-- Post Wrap Start-->
<div class="post hentry ivycat-post">

    <!--    This outputs the post TITLE -->
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/2017/05/03/blog-jinan/">Blog Jinan</a></h2>

    <!--    This outputs the post EXCERPT.  To display full content including images and html, 
        replace the_excerpt(); with the_content();  below. -->
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <p>Hi~ aku Jinan dari team T~ blog SweeTie kali ini aku yang tulis<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.2.1/svg/1f60a.svg" scale="0"> Pertama-tama aku mau ucapin terima kasih sama kalian yang selalu dukung aku, kemarin-kemarin jadwalku padat sekali karena ujian sekolah, tapi berkat kalian, sekarang aku sudah melewatinya<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.2.1/svg/1f642.svg" scale="0"> Aku udah lulus SMA loh, cie <img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.2.1/svg/1f602.svg" scale="0"> &nbsp;Ga kerasa banget udah 3 tahun aku belajar di […]</p>
    </div>

    <!--    This outputs the post META information -->
    <div class="entry-utility">
                    <span class="cat-links">
                <span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links">Posted in</span> <a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/category/blog/" rel="category tag">Blog</a>            </span>
            <span class="meta-sep">|</span>
                            <span class="tag-links">
                <span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links">Tagged</span> <a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/tag/jinan/" rel="tag">jinan</a>, <a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/tag/jkt48/" rel="tag">JKT48</a>, <a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/tag/team-t/" rel="tag">team T</a>           </span>
            <span class="meta-sep">|</span>
                <span class="comments-link"><a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/2017/05/03/blog-jinan/#comments">16 Comments</a></span>
            </div>
</div>
<!-- // Post Wrap End -->

<!-- I NEED TO PUT THE AD-TAGS IN HERE -->

<!-- NOTE: If you need to make changes to this file, copy it to your current theme's main
    directory so your changes won't be overwritten when the plugin is upgraded. -->

<!-- Post Wrap Start-->
<div class="post hentry ivycat-post">

    <!--    This outputs the post TITLE -->
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/2017/05/02/ngebolang-bareng-fia/">Ngebolang Bareng Fia</a></h2>

    <!--    This outputs the post EXCERPT.  To display full content including images and html, 
        replace the_excerpt(); with the_content();  below. -->
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <p>Bismillah, Halo semua! Ini tulisan blog aku yang kedua hehe baru dikit ya. &nbsp; Minggu terakhir bulan april alhamdulillah team T dapet banyak kegiatan on air dan off air! Dari hari kamis team T seperti biasa ada show RKJ di theater, lanjut hari Jum’at team T ada di acara Mama Amy (kedua kalinya Team T […]</p>
    </div>

    <!--    This outputs the post META information -->
    <div class="entry-utility">
                    <span class="cat-links">
                <span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links">Posted in</span> <a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/category/blog/" rel="category tag">Blog</a>            </span>
            <span class="meta-sep">|</span>
                            <span class="tag-links">
                <span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links">Tagged</span> <a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/tag/fia/" rel="tag">fia</a>, <a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/tag/fidly-immanda-zahra/" rel="tag">fidly immanda zahra</a>, <a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/tag/jkt48/" rel="tag">JKT48</a>, <a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/tag/melati/" rel="tag">melati</a>, <a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/tag/team-t/" rel="tag">team T</a>           </span>
            <span class="meta-sep">|</span>
                <span class="comments-link"><a href="http://blog.jkt48.com/team-t/2017/05/02/ngebolang-bareng-fia/#comments">9 Comments</a></span>
            </div>
</div>
<!-- // Post Wrap End -->
```

and you can read above that code like this `<!-- I NEED TO PUT THE AD-TAGS IN HERE -->`

In the middle of code that produces by `the_content()`. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you going to put `<!-- I NEED TO PUT THE AD-TAGS IN HERE -->` in content? If, yes there is a for-sure way then.

Comment: yes. I want to put the code at that specific place. Between the first post end and second post start. but that's just an example. In the practice, I want to put the `<!-- I NEED TO PUT THE AD-TAGS IN HERE -->` after the third post end, and so on @AmitChauhan

Answer (score 3):

If you want a specific place to add your codes, you could [build a shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) and then you could place something like `[place-add]` in your content in the exact place where you want the ad to appear.

If you don't want to add a shortcode to your text, you can build a [filter on `the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content). In that case you need to define a general place to instert the codes, for instance right before the second paragraph. That would work like this:

```php
add_filter ('the_content','wpse265825_add_ad');
function wpse265825_add_ad($content) {
  $ad = 'this is my ad code';
  // find the second paragraph
  $pos = strpos($content, '<p>', strpos($content, '<p>') + 1);
  // insert code in that position
  $content = substr_replace($content, $ad, $pos, 0);
  return $content;
  }
```

(I didn't test the code, so some debugging may be necessary)

Comment: I'm really new on wordpress. can I put the function on the themes file ? or I need to put on the other file ?

Comment: You can add functions in `fucntions.php` or can include any other file in which  you can keep all of your custom functions.

Comment: am I need to call the function ? or the `add_filter ('the_content','wpse265825_add_ad');` is already called the function ? because I can't see any changes happen with `the_content()` value..

Comment: You put the filter and the corresponding function in your child theme's `functions.php`. You can echo something in the function to see if the filter gets called at all, then tweak the function to get the ad where you want it.

Comment: ah the code works ! but it's put the `this is my ad code` on above the first `<!-- Post Wrap Start-->`. and a question, are these filter can do repetation ? like if I have 6 posts, I will show the `this is my ad code`  after the third post and so on ??

Comment: This is a filter to `the_content`, so it is called on every post. Your question was about inserting something inside a post. Now you seem to want to insert something between posts.

Comment: oh no. so I was asking the wrong question :( sorry. But yes, your code works as it should. and yes, I want to insert the ads-tags between the post. are you know about that ? If yes, then I will make new question for it. *edit, I'm not trying to insert the ads-tags to the post, but want to loop the post and the ads-tags with it. if it was using `while(have_post)`, I can do it easily.

Comment: That would involve modifying the main loop in the theme. Read this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114074/insert-custom-div-between-posts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58245/discussion-between-m-argus-chopin-gyver-and-cjbj).